# Add samples to given set to match distribution

Tags: sampling, mean, matching

I have a distribution from which I can draw random (iid) samples. I also have a (non-random) "sample" from that distribution that is given and skews heavily towards the lower end of it. I would now like to draw samples from the distribution to "fill in the gaps".

I know the mean of the distribution and I would like to draw another sample such that at least the final average of all samples matches the expected value (or everything looks just like a random sample from the distribution). I was thinking I could (maybe iteratively!?) draw a random sample and then reject or accept it based on some criteria, but I don't know what it would be exactly.

The number of additional samples I can draw is fixed and usually larger than the number of given values.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could approximate this is to draw a large random sample from your target distribution, find the nearest neighbors of your fixed samples, and replace those "nearby" random samples with the fixed samples. This would require a large enough sample to ensure that each fixed point has a neighbor that's "reasonably" close, how close that needs to be will depend on your application. With a very large random sample, you should naturally see random samples that very nearly approximate your fixed points, so swapping them out for the fixed points will have little effect on the original distribution that you drew from. You're not guaranteed that all moments of the "fixed" distribution will be identical to the original, but it will effectively approximate the entire distribution and not just selected aspects like the mean or variance.